# Talend S3 CSV to Redshift Handling Missing Data

Tags: amazon-web-services, syntax-error, talend

I have a CSV flat file loaded in S3 that will occasionally have an empty value in the columns delimited by commas, such as:`"ColumnValue1,,ColumnValue3,...etc"` 
 noting the `",,"` as the missing value in the CSV for example. Below is the very basic move from S3 to Redshift setup in Talend using the tDBBulkExec component:

[image]

Upon mapping the columns as below, and running:

[image]

Throws the error given those missing values in the source file:

```
Exception in component tDBBulkExec_1 (tncretail_opportunity)
java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "," 
Position: 100;
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.messages.inbound.ErrorResponse.toErrorException(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGMessagingContext.handleErrorResponse(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGMessagingContext.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.jdbc.communications.InboundMessagesPipeline.getNextMessageOfClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGMessagingContext.doMoveToNextClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGMessagingContext.getBindComplete(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGClient.handleErrorsScenario1(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGClient.handleErrors(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGClient.directExecuteExtraMetadata(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.redshift.dataengine.PGQueryExecutor.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.jdbc.common.SStatement.executeNoParams(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.jdbc.common.SStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.amazon.support.exceptions.ErrorException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "," 
Position: 100;
```

How can I amend this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using Talend for a while to do exactly what your doing there are a few key differences to what i do and this pattern that i would recommend.

1. your issue is most likely the fact you haven't specified the db column names these need to be specified and unique. (the database use's these to relate back to the schema)
2. Unless you have a specific reason for using TdB components don't use them instead use the pre-built specific connectors IE tRedshiftBulkExec.
3. a Redshift bulk file is delimited csv to my knowledge but may not necessarily fit the exact specification for one so your use of that component may be erroneous.

My recommendations for you to resolve are to either

1. extract the CSV from s3 convert to a bulk file then upload to Redshift (you could use 
   ts3list-->ts3get-'onComOK'->TfileInputDelimited-->TRedshiftOutputBulkExecute
2. alternatively you could issue a copy command with TRedshiftRow
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html

I would also double check the delimited file for corruption and consider using Text Enclosures (your text may contain a comma somewhere)